# How to load a file to a specific path in a Container with ConfigMap?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the [Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/spark) to deploy Spark to Kubernetes in GCE. I want to provide a custom `spark-defaults.conf` file in a ConfigMap to be deployed to spark-master path `/opt/bitnami/spark/conf`.

But I don't understand how can I make another file `custom-keys.yaml` to be deployed to the same path that is referenced from the `spark-defaults.conf`? 
The [documentation](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/spark#using-custom-configuration) only describes how to override default spark configuration. What is the correct way to load extra files and jars in this case?

I've specified a ConfigMap for spark-master in the `values.yaml`:

```
master:
  ## Set a custom configuration by using an existing configMap with the configuration file.
  ##
   configurationConfigMap: master-config
```

**master-config.yaml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: master-config
data:
  {{ (.Files.Glob "files/spark-defaults.conf").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

Comment: Are you using default image? If you are trying to put your jars and configs in the image, maybe you need to customize the image you need to edit the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-spark.git) and rebuild the image

Answer (score 0):

The ConfigMap name can be provided on deployment time.

```
helm install <Name> bitnami/spark --set master.configurationConfigMap=master-config
```